# Whether it's necessary for a grammar to be ambiguous when it is both left recursive and right recursive

Tags: context-free, compilers, recursion, parsers

I read somewhere that if a grammar is left recursive as well as right recursive, then it is not necessarily ambiguous.

I couldn't make up my mind on this statement. How can a grammar which is both left recursive as well as right recursive not have more than one parse tree for a single string.

Am I right? If not, please provide a counter example whereby my assumption can be proved wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean a **grammar** with left and right recursive rules, or a single **production rule** with left and right recursive alternatives?

If a single production rule is both left and right recursive, the grammar is ambiguous. For example, the following rule

$A \to \alpha A \mid A \alpha$

has the following two (left-most) derivations:

$A \Rightarrow \alpha A \Rightarrow \alpha A \alpha $ corresponding to the grouping $(\alpha (A\alpha)$

$A \Rightarrow A \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha A \alpha $ corresponding to the grouping 
$((\alpha A) \alpha)$

But a grammar can have left recursive and right recursive rules in different production rules and that can be unambiguous. For example, the following grammar:

$\begin{align*}
  S &\to X \mid Y \\
  X &\to X b \\
  Y &\to a Y \\
 \end{align*}$

In this grammar, $X$ and $Y$ are left and right recursive, respectively, but the grammar is unambiguous.

Comment: Hi @Wickoo, thanks for the answer. I just had one more question... Can we have a case where there is only one production in the grammar, which can be both left recursive and right recursive, and this grammar is not ambiguous?

Comment: You mean something like $A \to A \alpha A$? First of all, such a grammar is useless, as it doesn't produce anything, so you need a second alternative like $ A \to b$ for example. In this case, yes, it is still ambiguous. It's like the case with `1+2+3`, for the grammar $E \to E + E \mid digit$ which can be left or right associative.

Comment: @Wickoo why is the grammar abilash mishra asked is useless? It looks useless because the example you wrote looks useless but you made no sort of general argument against such a production rule. So to me (a non expert in PL) - it's unclear if it's useless.

Comment: Have you fully read my comment? I said why it’s useless, it cannot produce any sentence. You need at least one more alternative